# Force Bing logo to bottom of map OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, bing-maps

Any way to force the logo position of a Bing layer in OpenLayers?  See this image for the strange location:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example online via JSFiddle or an excerpt from your code? It seems CSS related but just an image is a small clue to help.

Comment: Note that the terms of use for Bing Maps states that you can not obscure the logo. See point 3.2 F: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the css tag `olControlAttribution` in style.css or override it in a style tag in the `<head>` element.

This tag looks like:

```
.olControlAttribution {
  font-size: smaller;
  right: 3px;
  bottom: 4.5em;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
```

so changing `bottom: 4.5em` to something like `bottom: 1px` ought to do it.

The source of [OpenLayers.Layer.Bing](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Layer/Bing.js) contains the comment that usage must be accompanied by `OpenLayers.Control.Attribution` and the css that applied to controls is always of the form olControl + ControlName.